# What questions can I ask someone to help them overcome the negative belief "whatever happens to me is going to be a big turmoil"?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling

Suppose a person has a strong negative belief that whatever happens to his life is going to cause him a big turmoil.

Then this person interprets all events from the view of this belief. The result is a person who's constantly panic-stricken.

The next time some life event occurs in this person's life, and he/she automatically jumps to negative conclusions due to this belief, then what questions could I ask him so as to help him see that an event isn't as critical as he thinks it is?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'cognitive-modeling'?

Comment: Also, all of this is very anecdotal and not framed in literature on psychology or neuroscience. This question is very likely to be put on hold.